# Gradient of kriged function in Openmdao

Tags: gradient, kriging, openmdao

I am currently coding an Multiple Gradient Descent algorithm, where I use kriged functions. 
My problem is that I can't find how to obtain the gradient of the kriged function (I tried to use linearize but I don't know how to make it work).

```
    from __future__ import print_function

from six import moves
from random import shuffle
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import math
from openmdao.braninkm import F, G, DF, DG

from openmdao.api import Group, Component,IndepVarComp
from openmdao.api import MetaModel
from openmdao.api import KrigingSurrogate, FloatKrigingSurrogate

def rand_lhc(b, k):
    # Calculates a random Latin hypercube set of n points in k dimensions within [0,n-1]^k hypercube.
    arr = np.zeros((2*b, k))
    row = list(moves.xrange(-b, b))
    for i in moves.xrange(k):
        shuffle(row)
        arr[:, i] = row
    return arr/b*1.2


class TrigMM(Group):
    ''' FloatKriging gives responses as floats '''

    def __init__(self):
        super(TrigMM, self).__init__()

        # Create meta_model for f_x as the response
        F_mm = self.add("F_mm", MetaModel())
        F_mm.add_param('X', val=np.array([0., 0.]))
        F_mm.add_output('f_x:float', val=0., surrogate=FloatKrigingSurrogate())
       # F_mm.add_output('df_x:float', val=0., surrogate=KrigingSurrogate().linearize)


        #F_mm.linearize('X', 'f_x:float')
        #F_mm.add_output('g_x:float', val=0., surrogate=FloatKrigingSurrogate())
        print('init ok')
        self.add('p1', IndepVarComp('X', val=np.array([0., 0.])))
        self.connect('p1.X','F_mm.X')       

        # Create meta_model for f_x as the response
        G_mm = self.add("G_mm", MetaModel())
        G_mm.add_param('X', val=np.array([0., 0.]))
        G_mm.add_output('g_x:float', val=0., surrogate=FloatKrigingSurrogate())
        #G_mm.add_output('df_x:float', val=0., surrogate=KrigingSurrogate().linearize)

        #G_mm.linearize('X', 'g_x:float')
        self.add('p2', IndepVarComp('X', val=np.array([0., 0.])))
        self.connect('p2.X','G_mm.X')                 

from openmdao.api import Problem

prob = Problem()
prob.root = TrigMM()
prob.setup()

u=4 
v=3 

#training avec latin hypercube

prob['F_mm.train:X'] = rand_lhc(20,2)
prob['G_mm.train:X'] = rand_lhc(20,2)

#prob['F_mm.train:X'] = rand_lhc(10,2)
#prob['G_mm.train:X'] = rand_lhc(10,2)
#prob['F_mm.linearize:X'] = rand_lhc(10,2)
#prob['G_mm.linearize:X'] = rand_lhc(10,2)
datF=[]
datG=[]
datDF=[]
datDG=[]

for i in range(len(prob['F_mm.train:X'])):
    datF.append(F(np.array([prob['F_mm.train:X'][i]]),u))
    #datG.append(G(np.array([prob['F_mm.train:X'][i]]),v))
data_trainF=np.fromiter(datF,np.float) 

for i in range(len(prob['G_mm.train:X'])):
    datG.append(G(np.array([prob['G_mm.train:X'][i]]),v))   
data_trainG=np.fromiter(datG,np.float) 

prob['F_mm.train:f_x:float'] = data_trainF
#prob['F_mm.train:g_x:float'] = data_trainG
prob['G_mm.train:g_x:float'] = data_trainG
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to be writing a Multiple Gradient Descent driver? If so, then OpenMDAO calculates the gradient from a param to an output at the `Problem` level using the `calc_gradient` method.

If you take a look at the source code for the pyoptsparse driver:

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py

The `_gradfunc` method is a callback function that returns the gradient of the constraints and objectives with respect to the design variables. The Metamodel component has built-in analytic gradients for all (I think) of our surrogates, so you don't even have to declare any there.

If this isn't what you are trying to do, then I may need a little more information about your application.